# Creating Modal Images Using PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, modal-dialog

I have created a page that places images in a table and I would like to able to click on each thumbnail to open a dialog box/popup window on top of the current page that displays a larger image. I have looked at w3schools.com (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp) and can easily replicate this for single, but not for multiple images. Is it possible? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Here is my PHP code that generates the table containing my images:

```
<div class="Row">
<?php
$counter = 0;
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $rs4 ) ) {
  ?>
<div class="Cell">
  <p> <img src ="<?php echo $row ['image']; ?>"></a> 
</div>
<?php++$counter;
if ( is_int( $counter / 3 ) ) {
  echo '</div><div class="Row">';
}
?>
<?php
}
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. Just put the related codes into a function (I name it trigger(var1) where the var1 is the image id).

**Just put your PHP scripts into the codes on generating the part on the images. (in the TABLE of the HTML below), you may change the TABLE to DIV if you wish**

Please see the codes below (Please click `"Run code snippet"` and try the effect):

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
//var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

/*
img.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

*/

function trigger(var1)
{
 modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = document.getElementById(var1).src;
  captionText.innerHTML = document.getElementById(var1).alt;

}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.xIMG {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.xIMG:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {  
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

<!-- Put your PHP scripts to generate the table BELOW with images -->

<table border=0><tr><td>
<img id="myImg" class=xIMG src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kza2t.jpg" alt="Picture 1" style="width:100%;max-width:300px" onclick="javascript:trigger('myImg');">
<td>
<img id="myImg2" class=xIMG src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzfgu.jpg" alt="Picture 2" style="width:100%;max-width:300px" onclick="javascript:trigger('myImg2');">
<td>
<img id="myImg3" class=xIMG src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL95G.jpg" alt="Picture 3" style="width:100%;max-width:300px" onclick="javascript:trigger('myImg3');">
</table>

<!-- END your PHP here --->


<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I got that working. Used the counter create the image id...minimal fiddling with the code. Thanks a million...works like a treat.